# How to drop multiple columns from Spark Data Frame?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one CSV in which some column headers and their corresponding values are null. I would like to know how can I drop columns which have name `null`?
Sample CSV is as follows:

```
"name"|"age"|"city"|"null"|"null"|"null"
"abcd"|"21" |"7yhj"|"null"|"null"|"null"
"qazx"|"31" |"iuhy"|"null"|"null"|"null"
"foob"|"51" |"barx"|"null"|"null"|"null"
```

I want to drop all the columns which has header has `null` such that output data frame will look like below:

```
"name"|"age"|"city"
"abcd"|"21" |"7yhj"
"qazx"|"31" |"iuhy"
"foob"|"51" |"barx"
```

When I load this CSV in spark, Spark appends number to null columns like shown below:

```
"name"|"age"|"city"|"null4"|"null5"|"null6"
"abcd"|"21" |"7yhj"|"null"|"null"|"null"
"qazx"|"31" |"iuhy"|"null"|"null"|"null"
"foob"|"51" |"barx"|"null"|"null"|"null"
```

---

> Solution found

Thanks @MaxU for the answer. My final solution is:

```
val filePath = "C:\\Users\\shekhar\\spark-trials\\null_column_header_test.csv"

val df = spark.read.format("csv")
.option("inferSchema", "false")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", "|")
.load(filePath)

val q = df.columns.filterNot(c => c.startsWith("null")).map(a => df(a))
// df.columns.filterNot(c => c.startsWith("null")) this part removes column names which start with null and returns array of string. each element of array represents column name

// .map(a => df(a)) converts elements of array into object of type Column
df.select(q:_*).show
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("null")))
```

Comment: you have forgotten to close it so you are missing one bracket.